# How do I update a Label with a numerical value with python?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have tried a lot of different things but nothing has worked so far.

I am trying to a Label(l1) increase or decrease by one each time the "+1"(b1) or "-1"(b2) button is pressed. But at the moment the Label just sits there and does nothing.

Here is the code in it's basic form without trying to update the label:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

p1 = 0

l1 = Label(root, textvariable = p1)
f1 = Frame(root)
b1 = Button(root, text = "+1", command = p1 + 1)
b2 = Button(root, text = "-1", command = p1 - 1)

l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f1.grid(row=1, column=0)

b1.pack(side="top")
b2.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- The `command` option of a `Button` takes a function and `p1 +/- 1` is not a function.
- The `textvariable` option of a `Label` takes a Tkinter variable, usually a `StringVar`, but here an `IntVar` is more appropriate.
- You are mixing `pack` and `grid` in `root`, which is not possible.

To do what you want, you nedd to define two functions, one that increases the value of the `IntVar` by 1 and the other that decreases it. Then, pass the functions to the `command` option of the buttons and pass the `IntVar` to the textvariable argument of the label:

```
import tkinter as tk

def increase():
    p1.set(p1.get() + 1)

def decrease():
    p1.set(p1.get() - 1)

root = tk.Tk()

p1 = tk.IntVar(root, 0)

l1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=p1)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="+1", command=increase)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text="-1", command=decrease)

l1.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works! I think I just didnt assign the IntVar correctly.